# A shelf and indistinguishable marbles - a counting problem

Tags: combinatorics

Problem:
A shelf contains $6$ separate compartments. In how many ways can
$4$ indistinguishable marbles be placed in the compartments?
Answer:
If the marbles were distinguishable then I claim the answer is
$6^4$. Let $c$ be the count we are looking for.
\begin{align*} 
c &= \dfrac{ 6^4 }{4!} = \dfrac{ 36(36) }{4(3)(2)} \\
c &= \dfrac{ 9(36) }{3(2)} = 3(18)\\
c &= 54
\end{align*}
However, the book gets: $126$. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Suppose there were $5$ marbles. Would you say these can be placed in the $6$ compartments in $(6^5)/(5!)$ ways? That's not even an integer.

Comment: I added an additional method of solution which directly compares the distributions of distinct and indistinguishable balls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the marbles are indistinguishable, what matters is how many marbles are placed in each compartment.  Let $x_i$, $1 \leq i \leq 6$, be the number of marbles placed in the $i$th compartment.  We wish to find the number of solutions of the equation
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 = 4 \tag{1}$$
in the nonnegative integers.

A particular solution of equation $1$ can be represented by a sequence of $4$ ones and $6 - 1 = 5$ addition signs.  For instance,
$$+ 1 + + + 1 1 + 1$$
corresponds to the solution $x_1 = 0$, $x_2 = 1$, $x_3 = x_4 = 0$, $x_5 = 2$, $x_6 = 1$.  The number of solutions of equation $1$ is the number of ways we can place $5$ addition signs in a row of four ones, which is
$$\binom{4 + 6 - 1}{6 - 1} = \binom{9}{5}$$
since we must choose which five of the nine positions required for four ones and five addition signs will be filled with addition signs.

As for your attempt, while it is true that there are $4!$ ways to permute an arrangement in which the same four compartments each receive one marble when the marbles are distinct, that does not apply to a distribution in which all four marbles are all placed in the first compartment.  There is only one way to place all the marbles in the first compartment.

**Addendum:**  Here is another way to solve the problem that more directly illustrates the relationship between distributions of distinct and indistinguishable marbles.

The number $4$ can be partitioned in five ways:
\begin{align*}
4 & = 4\\
  & = 3 + 1\\
  & = 2 + 2\\
  & = 2 + 1 + 1\\
  & = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1
\end{align*}

**Distributing $4$ indistinguishable marbles to $6$ compartments**

*All four marbles are placed in the same compartment*:  There are six ways to select the compartment that receives all four marbles.

*Three marbles are placed in one compartment and the other marble is placed in a different compartment*:  There are six ways to select the compartment which will receive three marbles and five ways to select which of the remaining compartments will receive the other marble.  Hence, there are $6 \cdot 5 = 30$ such distributions.

*Two marbles each are placed in two compartments*:  There are $\binom{6}{2}$ ways to select which two compartments will each receive two marbles.

*Two marbles are placed in one compartment and one marble each is placed in two other compartments*:  There are six ways to select the compartment that will receive two marbles and $\binom{5}{2}$ ways to select which two of the other five compartments will each receive one of the remaining two marbles.  Hence, there are $\binom{6}{1}\binom{5}{2}$ such distributions.

*One marble each is placed in four of the compartments*:  There are $\binom{6}{4}$ ways to select which four of the six compartments will each receive one marble.

*Total*:  The number of ways four indistinguishable marbles can be distributed to six compartments is
$$\binom{6}{1} + \binom{6}{1}\binom{5}{1} + \binom{6}{2} + \binom{6}{1}\binom{5}{2} + \binom{6}{4}$$

**Distributing $4$ distinct marbles to $6$ compartments**

You are correct that there are $6^4$ such distributions since there are six choices for each of the four marbles.  However, the problem can also be solved by using the same cases we considered for indistinguishable marbles.

*All four marbles are placed in the same compartment*:  There are still six ways to select the compartment which will receive all four marbles.

*Three marbles are placed in one compartment and the other marble is placed in a different compartment*:  There are six ways to select the compartment that will receive three marbles, $\binom{4}{3}$ ways to select the marbles that will be placed in that compartment, and five ways to select which of the remaining compartments will receive the remaining marble.  There are $\binom{6}{1}\binom{4}{3}\binom{5}{1}$ such distributions.

*Two marbles each are placed in two compartments*:  There are $\binom{6}{2}$ ways to select which two compartments will each receive two marbles and $\binom{4}{2}$ ways to select which two of the four marbles will be placed in the leftmost of those compartments.  Hence, there are $\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}$ such distributions.

*Two marbles are placed in one compartment and one marble each is placed in two other compartments*:  There are six ways to select the compartment that will receive two marbles, $\binom{4}{2}$ ways to select which two marbles will be placed in that compartment,  $\binom{5}{2}$ ways to select which two of the other five compartments will each receive one of the remaining two marbles, and $2!$ ways to distribute the remaining two marbles to those two compartments.  Hence, there are $\binom{6}{1}\binom{4}{2}\binom{5}{2}2!$ such distributions.

*One marble each is placed in four of the compartments*:  There are $\binom{6}{4}$ ways to select which four of the six compartments will each receive one marble and $4!$ ways to distribute the marbles to those four compartments.  Hence, there are $\binom{6}{4}4!$ such distributions.

*Total*:  The number of ways four distinct marbles can be distributed to six compartments is
$$\binom{6}{1} + \binom{6}{1}\binom{4}{3}\binom{5}{1} + \binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2} + \binom{6}{1}\binom{4}{2}\binom{5}{2}2! + \binom{6}{4}4!$$

As you can see by comparing corresponding terms in the distributions of distinct and indistinguishable marbles, it was only appropriate to divide by $4!$ when each of the four marbles was placed in a different compartment, which is why your answer was too small.